# Text in cell as input, not cell number

Tags: excel, command, cell, vlookup

I want the text in my cell to be my input for `VLOOKUP`.

Let's say `B3:D10` is written in cell `E5`.

So, I want to refer to cell `E5` and get the range `B3:D10`, not the value itself.

I used the following formula `=VLOOKUP(E4,E5,8,0)` but it reads `E5` as the table array.

I also tried `=VLOOKUP(E4,text(E5,0),8,0)` but turns out as `#Value!` error.

Comment: Use the INDIRECT function. =VLOOKUP(E4,INDIRECT(E5),8,0)

Answer (score 1):

i think you have few mistakes. Range B3:D10 has only 3 columns so you can not set col_index_num to 8 because will cause an error.

See the image please:

[image]

- E5 - Yellow area is the range B3:D10
- E4 the text to search for
- G3 hase the below formula:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP(E4,INDIRECT(E5),2,0)
  ```

**Tips:**

- Fix the range you search using "$". Example: $B$3:$D$10
- Use IFERROR to avoid error if search value not appear in range

  ```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4,INDIRECT(E5),2,0),"Value not appear in range")
  ```

Comment: thank you so much! tried the indirect and it works :)